# Chart JS - Remember hidden label state after page refresh

Tags: javascript, chart.js

In Chart.js it's possible to hide labels from the graph programmatically using the "hidden" parameter. When a user clicks on a label and hides it, I would like to store this state change in a cookie/cache, so when the user returns to the page, the label is already hidden. Is this possible? How can I do this?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this ?

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Chart.js v2.9.3

I guess you already know how to deal with cookies, here is the code that overwrites the default function that gives you an index that you can store in a cookie for further use.

```
onClick(e, legendItem) {
    // Get the index
    const index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
    //index alert
    alert("dataset index " + index + " was clicked")

    // this table object
    const ci = this.chart;

    // show/hide dataset
    var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(index);
    meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null? !ci.data.datasets[index].hidden : null;

    // We hid a dataset ... rerender the chart
    ci.update();
},
```

Copy paste this code inside **options** > **legend: {Here}**

Finally, here is a jsFiddle live example.
https://jsfiddle.net/pt0s95r7/1/